# Best practices for managing simple "description" tables

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization

The application I'm working has contains lots of small tables that simply hold descriptive data (sex, entity type, marital status, primary branch, customer size, etc.).

We have about 40 of these types of tables now and it's growing about 7-8 tables per year.

We append each table with "desc_name" to make them easier to find.

Is there a best practice per se for managing these tables? Should they be their own tables, or should I lump them into a single, larger table?

All of the tables are properly indexed so I don't know if there's a performance hit with having a single tables vs multiple tables. How does everyone else do this? Or does it really matter? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types of tables are called domain tables or reference tables.

A simple domain table is Gender

```
ID      Code     Description
--      ----     -----------
0       M        Male
1       F        Female
2       T        Transgender
```

Usually, domain tables don't need any indexes other than the primary or clustering index, because these types of tables are so small that a full table read is faster than reading the index, then reading the table.  If a domain table has more than 1,000 rows, then an index on the code column would help.

Some shops have one master domain table, and other shops have separate domain tables for each domain.  It doesn't matter which way you go, neither for performance nor for disk usage and access.

You could put domain tables in their own MySQL database (USE database, not physical database).  Prefixing the tables is another good way to identify the domain tables.

Comment: +1 for the example. I once saw code which simplified a "gender" field into a boolean IsMale. I cannot tell you how annoying that was to the females on the team!

Comment: @KingCronus: Even with my example, the men can say they come first, while the women can say men are zeroes. :-)  Sometimes, there's no pleasing everyone.

Comment: Today I learned they are called "domain/reference" tables. I didn't think they had a formal name. :) I think I will keep it the way it is since it doesn't appear it will hurt anything. Thank you for the great explanation!